# Git-tfs reset to remote

Tags: git, git-tfs

I want to reset to the state of a remote.

Using normal git I would do something like `git reset --hard origin/HEAD`.

I am using git-tfs. Does anyone know how to do this with git-tfs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was working out how git-tfs constructs the remote URI.

In my case the following worked:

`git reset --hard tfs/default`

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what is 'tfs' and what is 'default' for you? As I am getting: ambiguous argument 'tfs/default': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: `[tfs-remote "default"]
 url = http://foo.com:8080/tfs/project/
 repository = $/project/subproject
 fetch = refs/remotes/default/master
 username = domain\\username
 password = mypassword`

Comment: ^ above is from my git config file (under .git directory)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following "built in" `git tfs reset-remote`, I dont know if this is what you wanted to do Ben?
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/reset-remote.md